# Should I attend an upcoming career fair for 2020 if I'm currently an intern until the end of 2019?

Tags: job-search, student

Just to clarify, this isn't a duplicate of similar questions where the OP isn't interested in a job but is asking if it is okay to still attend a job fair.

Rather, I'm currently interning at a company I really like until the end of 2019. Everything's going well so far, and they have a pretty high conversion/onboarding rate for interns once they finish their term.

However, there is obviously no *guarantee* that I will be given a full-time position with them once my internship ends. I've had a couple recruiters reach out to me about an upcoming career fair at my university and was wondering what I should do. I definitely intend to get full-time employment after I graduate.

What should I do? Should I respectfully decline the invitations to drop by those companies' booths during the career fair? They found me through a networking/job site (not LinkedIn). Additionally, would it be disrespectful to my current company if I were to attend the career fair? I have no intention of ending the internship prematurely.

Comment: What makes you think it is not ok to attend a 2020 event if your internship ends before 2020?

Answer (score 8):

Go.  Look for a full time job for after you graduate.

The only reason not to go would be if you had accepted an offer to a full time position already.

Comment: Or if he wouldn't be available because it was still too early in the year, or he wouldn't graduate on time.

Comment: Your company might even give you a job when they see you're taking initiative to go out and look.

Answer (score 4):

Go. It's not disrespectful, as the company you're interning at hasn't (and might not) extend a permanent offer. Keep plenty of irons in the fire.